# Is it wise to delete the default webapps from a Tomcat-based docker image?

Tags: docker, tomcat

I am containerizing an older Java web application with Docker.  My Dockerfile pulls an official Tomcat image from Docker Hub (specifically, `tomcat:8.5.49-jdk8-openjdk`), copies my .WAR file into the `webapps/` directory, and copies in some idiosyncratic configuration files and dependencies.  It works.

Now I know that Tomcat comes out-of-the-box with a few directories under `webapps/`, including the "`manager`" app, and some others: `ROOT`, `docs`, `examples`, `host-manager`.  I'm thinking I ought to delete these, lest one of my users access them, which might be a security risk and is unprofessional at the least.

Is it a best practice to delete those installed-by-default web apps from an official Tomcat image?  Is there any downside to doing so?  It seems logical to me, but a web search didn't turn up any expert opinion either way.

Answer (score 3):

Every folder under `webapps` represents discrete Web Application contained within **Tomcat Servlet Container** after the server startup and deployment.

None of those web applications have any implicit or explicit correlation with either **`Catalina`**, **`Jasper`** or any other system component of Tomcat.

You should be quite OK to remove all those folders (apps) unless you need to have a `Manager` tool/application to manage your deployments and server. Even that can be installed again later on.

Comment: One might add that shortly after this question was asked the default applications were removed from `webapps` (cf. [this pull request](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/pull/181)) in the images published by Docker.